# $x + 3^x < 4$ exponential equation

Tags: calculus

might be trivial for some but I have problems with this equation.
I know the answer for $x + 3^x = 4$ is $x = 1$, however I only see that through visual analysis. I searched for an answer on this specific problem online (since it's in the Michael Spivak Calculus book Chapter 1 Problem 4(xii)) and all I was able to find is "by visual analysis... you can see..." which doesn't answer my question

How can you solve this analytically?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you want to solve the **equation** $x+3^x=4.\;$  For this 
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1 which handles the case $p^x=ax+b$.

Comment: I don't think you can solve it algebraically.  But let $f(x) = x+3^x$.  $f'(x) = 1 + \ln3*3^x > 0$.  So the function is strictly and monotonically increasing.  And it's continuous.  So every $f(x) =c$ will have exactly one solution for each c in the range of $f$.  It's pretty clear all reals are in range so all reals have soultion.  $f(0) = 1$ so $f(x) = 4$ has solution at some $x > 0$.  $f(2) = 11$ so the solution is in $0 < x < 2$.  It doesn't take too much effort to eventually try $f(1) = 4$.

Answer (score 3):

From $f'(x)=1+3^x\ln 3>0$, you see that the function is monotonic increasing and cannot have more than one root, which you know to be $x=1$.

Then

$$x<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = x+3^x$

$f'(x) = 1 + ln(3)3^x$ on $x \ge 1$

$f'(x) > 0$, so function is growing up. So minimum in $x=1$ (for this set of points).
So for other points function will be less than $4$.

$x<1$

Comment: Also you could use: sum of continuous functions is continuous function

Comment: Your derivative is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the derivative is wrong (most probably a typo), as it should be $\;\log 3\;$ instead of $\;\log x\;$ there, but the whole argument is correct. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio my bad

Comment: @DonAntonio: the discussion states $x\ge1$ (so what for $x<1$ ?), then claims a minimum at $x=1$ (?) and concludes that other values won't exceed $4$. I wouldn't call that a typo but a completely misleading answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is not my opinion. Certainly some things could be sharpened and written in a smoother way, yet the answer is basically correct imo. I understood from what's written in the answer that :$\;f'(x)>0\;$ and thus the function grows always (and thus any value the function obtains it is obtained at one unique point). The fact that $\;x=1\;$ is a minimum is something, I guess, that can be left to the OP. I can't see how this, with all its tiny mistakes, is "completely misleading" ...

Comment: @DonAntonio: restricting the domain to $x\ge1$ is. You can't justify an answer which is correct by chance.

Answer (score 0):

In general:
$$x+a^x=b$$
$$-a^x=x-b$$
$$-e^{x\ln a}=x-b$$
Write $b-x=z$:
$$-e^{(b-z)\ln a}=-z$$
$$e^{b\ln a-z\ln a}=z$$
$$e^{b\ln a}=ze^{z\ln a}$$
$$\ln a\cdot e^{b\ln a}=z\ln a\cdot e^{z\ln a}$$
Apply the [Lambert W function's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) defining relation $x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$:
$$z\ln a=W(\ln a\cdot e^{b\ln a})$$
$$z=\frac{W(a^b\ln a)}{\ln a}$$
$$x=b-\frac{W(a^b\ln a)}{\ln a}$$

---

The above derivation is for $x+a^x=b$. To solve $x+a^x<b$, consider the argument to Lambert's W, $w=a^b\ln a$:

- If $w=-\frac1e$ or $w\ge0$ then $W(w)$ can take on only one value. The corresponding solution to $x+a^x=b$ – call it $x_0$ – is such that the inequality holds for $x<x_0$.
- If $-\frac1e<w<0$ then $W(w)$ can take on two values, leading to two solutions for $x+a^x=b$: $x_0$ and $x_1$. The inequality holds for $x_0<x<x_1$.
- Else, $W(w)$ is not defined and the inequality does not hold anywhere.

Comment: You forgot to solve the inequation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust OK, does this please you now?

Comment: It has to please the OP rather than me.